# Use ng-repeat's $index variable within an AngularJs expression

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an `ng-repeat` div that I need to use the `$index` variable to build out an expression. Consider the following:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in myItems track by $index">
   This will throw an error: {{myItemId_{{$index}}.someProperty}}
</div>
```

If I have a `$scope` variable called "myItemId_0", how do I use $index within a curly braces {{}} expression? I have tried omitting the curly braces for the $index variable, this but this doesn't work either:

{{myItemId_$index.someProperty}}

Comment: I don't have much to add to the answers below, but here's how I'd go about it. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vNNBgj

Comment: do you also have a `{{myItemId_{{$index}}` for all `$index` values?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since it's a variable on scope, create a function that retrieves your property via bracket notation.

HTML:

```
{{getByIndex($index, "someProperty")}}
```

Controller:

```
$scope.getByIndex = function(index, someProperty) {
    var propertyName = "myItemId_" + index;

    return $scope[propertyName][someProperty];
}
```

However, the logical solution is to not access your properties in this way at all, but rather use item which is already available from your ng-repeat.

HTML:

```
div ng-repeat="item in betterItems track by $index">
    {{item.someProperty}}
</div>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.betterItems = [];
angular.forEach(myItems, function (i) {
    $scope.betterItems.push(createMappedItem(i));
}
```

Even if you have to map your collection to a new collection (or reuse the same if need be), you can still access that original item.  It's cleaner and much easier to maintain.  In addition, retrieval by index can be very dangerous if you start mutating the collection.

Comment: This is the better answer. You shouldn't have a bunch of `foo_1`, `foo_2`, `foo_N` variables in your scope.

Comment: @Agop agreed, although at times there are extenuating circumstances that prevent you for doing so, for whatever reason.  However, if you can avoid that type of maintenance nightmare, you'll always be better off :).